# Delete all folders except 123, 1234 and 12345

Tags: batch-file

With below I can delete all folders in C:\Temp expect folder 123 but I want to add another folder 1234 and 12345 that should not be deleted once you run the script, can some help me how i can add folder 1234 & 12345.

```
pushd "C:\Temp" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (if /I not "%%~nxD"=="123" rd /S /Q "%%~D")
for %%F in ("*") do (del "%%~F")
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
 set "zapme=Y"
 for %%O IN (123 1234 12345) do if /I "%%~nxD"=="%%O" set "zapme="
 if defined zapme rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
```

using `zapme` as a flag.